# How to make the current user Authenticated without login

Tags: asp.net, cookies

How to make the current user Authenticated without login.

In other words, what should I do to get `true` when I ask `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` without login?

Should I create a cookie manually? if so, what's its name, what's its value!!

I hope it's clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FormsAuthenication.SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx).